# Vector of (Structs having vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, initialization

The following piece of code as stated in Bjarne Stroustroup's C++: Programming and Principles

```
struct Day {
    vector <double> hour { vector <double> (24,-7777)}
};
struct Month {
    vector <Day> day {32};
};
```

This piece of code initializes 32 days, each day as a `vector` of 24 hours initialized with `-7777`;

The question is why list initializer `{32}` creates 32 days. **Isn't it supposed to initialize day `vector` with 32 as a initial value instead of creating 32 members?**

Comment: how would `32` be an appropriate initial value for  a (singular) `Day` object ?

Comment: `vector<Day> day{32}` is similar to `vector<Day> day(32)`. If you look at the vector definition, it says the argument is element count of the vector

Comment: @BAdhi Sure about it? Only parameters enclosed in (n) creates vector of n items... whereas {n} initializes a possible vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [list initialiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization),

> Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
> All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument,
>   or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default
>   values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a
>   single argument of type `std::initializer_list`
>
> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T`
>   participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
>   consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>   that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage
>   produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>   copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>   copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

`day` is of type `vector <Day>`, whose [constructor taking `std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) as parameter expects an `std::initializer_list<Day>`, which can't be constructed from the braced-initializer `{32}`. Then the [constructor taking `size_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is used and construct the `vector` with 32 default-inserted instances of `Day`.

On the other hand, if `Day` could be initialized from an `int`, e.g. has a constructor taking `int`, then `std::initializer_list<Day>` could be constructed from `{32}` because of the implicit conversion from `int` to `Day`, then `vector <Day> day {32};` would construct the `vector` with one element initialized from `32`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JCYHLGqZRMWXhbGo)

Answer (score 0):

The one parameter initializer list is matched to the vector [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking one parameter, which allocates that many elements. In this case 32.